# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment (Minecraft Server)

Tags: java, minecraft

My minecraft server has been randomly crashing after we switched hosts from google to OVH. I've been trying to resolve this issue for around 1 1/2 weeks now but am now forced to ask for help.

Minecraft server version: PaperSpigot 1.8.8
Linux Version: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Java Version: I assume 1.8 but I can't find whilst doing java -version

This is my error report...

```
Link > https://pastebin.com/6D1WmYf4

  A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f29ac94d20b, pid=32, tid=0x00007f295f2daae8

 JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 Derivative: IcedTea 3.4.0
 Distribution: Custom build (Fri Jun 16 13:41:54 GMT 2017)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [ld-musl-x86_64.so.1+0x5020b]  memcpy+0x24
 Core dump written. Default location: /home/container/core or core.32

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
 instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.


---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000055dda9e57800):  JavaThread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 101" [_thread_in_native, id=4848, stack(0x00007f295f1da000,0x00007f295f2daaa8)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x00007f2966abe000

Registers:
RAX=0x000055ddb9258fe0, RBX=0x000055dda598e340, RCX=0x00000000000011fd, RDX=0x0000000000009a52
RSP=0x00007f295f2d7fb8, RBP=0x0000000000009a52, RSI=0x00007f2966abdffb, RDI=0x000055ddb9259a48
R8 =0x0000000000009a81, R9 =0x0000000000000028, R10=0x00007f299c039cd8, R11=0x00000005a65020d0
R12=0x0000000000004b03, R13=0x00007f2966abd565, R14=0x0000000000009a52, R15=0x000055ddab766de0
RIP=0x00007f29ac94d20b, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f295f2d7fb8)
0x00007f295f2d7fb8:   00007f29aae2dc42 0000000000000028
0x00007f295f2d7fc8:   00000000a598e460 8a1b4b0300008a1b
0x00007f295f2d7fd8:   0000000000280000 00007f295f2d8000
0x00007f295f2d7fe8:   000055dda4cf7780 0000000000000028
0x00007f295f2d7ff8:   00007f295f2d8097 000055dda598e340
0x00007f295f2d8008:   000055ddace8ff00 0000000044d72e95
0x00007f295f2d8018:   00007f29aae2e7f4 00007f295f2d8070
0x00007f295f2d8028:   01c4249595be95e0 00007f295f2d8498
0x00007f295f2d8038:   0000000000000028 000055dda9e579e0
0x00007f295f2d8048:   0000000000000001 000000007ba7a2b3
0x00007f295f2d8058:   000055dda598e340 00007f295f2d84c8
0x00007f295f2d8068:   00007f29aae2c96f 6d6978616d2f6562
0x00007f295f2d8078:   746165662f776476 6472616f62726568
0x00007f295f2d8088:   622f702f65726f63 7373616c632e622f
0x00007f295f2d8098:   000055ddaa0d0000 000055ddaa0d80e0
0x00007f295f2d80a8:   0000000063af27c8 000055dda6461780
0x00007f295f2d80b8:   00007f29abfbf218 3a303a3a303a303a
0x00007f295f2d80c8:   000055dda9e57800 3a303a303a303a30
0x00007f295f2d80d8:   313a303a63af2a30 3735383639313035
0x00007f295f2d80e8:   5354524145483a35 3664303a303a303a
0x00007f295f2d80f8:   65392d3864313863 2d653235342d3032
0x00007f295f2d8108:   0000000474f95908 00000005a64f7280
0x00007f295f2d8118:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f295f2d8128:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f295f2d8138:   0000000000000000 0000002d00000005
0x00007f295f2d8148:   00000005a64f71f8 00007f29ffffffff
0x00007f295f2d8158:   0000000000000000 00000005a64f71b8
0x00007f295f2d8168:   00007f295f2d81e8 00007f295cee5a18
0x00007f295f2d8178:   00007f290000002d 00000005a64f71f8
0x00007f295f2d8188:   000055dd00000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f295f2d8198:   2d346364612d6263 6162336630626336
0x00007f295f2d81a8:   000055ddaa0d80e0 7461654d626f4d0a 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f29ac94d20b)
0x00007f29ac94d1eb:   83 fa 08 72 14 f7 c7 07 00 00 00 74 0c a4 48 ff
0x00007f29ac94d1fb:   ca f7 c7 07 00 00 00 75 f4 48 89 d1 48 c1 e9 03
0x00007f29ac94d20b:   f3 48 a5 83 e2 07 74 05 a4 ff ca 75 fb c3 48 89
0x00007f29ac94d21b:   f8 48 29 f0 48 39 d0 0f 83 bf ff ff ff 48 89 d1 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000055ddb9258fe0 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000055dda598e340 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00000000000011fd is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000009a52 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f295f2d7fb8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000055dda9e57800
RBP=0x0000000000009a52 is an unknown value
RSI=0x00007f2966abdffb is an unknown value
RDI=0x000055ddb9259a48 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000009a81 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000028 is an unknown value
R10=0x00007f299c039cd8 is at entry_point+88 in (nmethod*)0x00007f299c039b10
R11=0x00000005a65020d0 is pointing into object: 0x00000005a6448a98

[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xb]

Stack: [0x00007f295f1da000,0x00007f295f2daaa8],  sp=0x00007f295f2d7fb8,  free space=1015k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ld-musl-x86_64.so.1+0x5020b]  memcpy+0x24

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 501  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(J[BZ)J (0 bytes) @ 0x00007f299c039cd8 [0x00007f299c039c80+0x58]
J 2606 C2 sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lsun/misc/Resource; (85 bytes) @ 0x00007f299c5f2ccc [0x00007f299c5f26e0+0x5ec]
J 7042 C2 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object; (5 bytes) @ 0x00007f299d0e8bf0 [0x00007f299d0e8540+0x6b0]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 469  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x00007f299c024463 [0x00007f299c024400+0x63]
J 8324 C2 org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class; (95 bytes) @ 0x00007f299d40bd44 [0x00007f299d40a7c0+0x1584]
J 8554 C2 org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; (7 bytes) @ 0x00007f299d0c5298 [0x00007f299d0c5260+0x38]
J 9079 C2 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class; (122 bytes) @ 0x00007f299d38bcc8 [0x00007f299d38b900+0x3c8]
J 3175 C2 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; (7 bytes) @ 0x00007f299c0b8120 [0x00007f299c0b80e0+0x40]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  be.maximvdw.featherboardcore.p.b.a.d(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+9
j  be.maximvdw.featherboardcore.o.g.e(Ljava/lang/String;)V+1
j  be.maximvdw.featherboardcore.o.g.b(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V+26
J 37948 C2 be.maximvdw.featherboardcore.l.h.b(Lorg/bukkit/entity/Player;Lorg/bukkit/scoreboard/Scoreboard;I)V (501 bytes) @ 0x00007f29a23335a4 [0x00007f29a2330e80+0x2724]
J 21964 C2 be.maximvdw.featherboard.scoreboard.ScoreboardGroup.send(Lorg/bukkit/entity/Player;)V (226 bytes) @ 0x00007f299ed96064 [0x00007f299ed94f00+0x1164]
J 25817 C2 be.maximvdw.featherboard.scoreboard.a.run()V (474 bytes) @ 0x00007f299fc6bc94 [0x00007f299fc6b760+0x534]
J 37262 C2 org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run()V (525 bytes) @ 0x00007f29a164e7b4 [0x00007f29a164e260+0x554]
J 29572 C2 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V (225 bytes) @ 0x00007f29a035bc30 [0x00007f29a035ba60+0x1d0]
J 37221 C1 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V (9 bytes) @ 0x00007f299d2b7e04 [0x00007f299d2b7d00+0x104]
J 35426 C1 java.lang.Thread.run()V (17 bytes) @ 0x00007f299f661584 [0x00007f299f661440+0x144]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000055ddb8661000 JavaThread "pool-7-thread-58" [_thread_blocked, id=5369, stack(0x00007f295edd4000,0x00007f295eed4aa8)]
  0x000055ddadb3d800 JavaThread "Keep-Alive-Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5368, stack(0x00007f295eed5000,0x00007f295efd5aa8)]
  0x000055ddac33c000 JavaThread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 108" [_thread_blocked, id=5307, stack(0x00007f295e1ca000,0x00007f295e2caaa8)]
  0x000055ddb8660800 JavaThread "Async Chat Thread - #14" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5302, stack(0x00007f295e9d2000,0x00007f295ead2aa8)]
  0x000055ddb8662800 JavaThread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 107" [_thread_blocked, id=5301, stack(0x00007f295f6df000,0x00007f295f7dfaa8)]
  0x000055ddaf2e2000 JavaThread "pool-7-thread-56" [_thread_blocked, id=5266, stack(0x00007f295ead3000,0x00007f295ebd3aa8)]
  0x000055ddade94800 JavaThread "MVStore background writer nio:/home/container/plugins/LiteBans/litebans.mv.db" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5231, stack(0x00007f295f5de000,0x00007f295f6deaa8)]
  0x000055dda68e8000 JavaThread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 106" [_thread_blocked, id=5113, stack(0x00007f295e6d1000,0x00007f295e7d1aa8)]
  0x000055dda6c88000 JavaThread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 105" [_thread_blocked, id=5053, stack(0x00007f295efd6000,0x00007f295f0d6aa8)]
  0x000055ddb00a5000 JavaThread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 104" [_thread_blocked, id=5037, stack(0x00007f295fce3000,0x00007f295fde3aa8)]
  0x000055dda5681000 JavaThread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 103" [_thread_blocked, id=5011, stack(0x00007f29647f0000,0x00007f29648f0aa8)]
  0x000055ddb5078000 JavaThread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 102" [_thread_blocked, id=4913, stack(0x00007f295f4dd000,0x00007f295f5ddaa8)]
=>0x000055dda9e57800 JavaThread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 101" [_thread_in_native, id=4848, stack(0x00007f295f1da000,0x00007f295f2daaa8)]
  0x000055ddafaa4800 JavaThread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 99" [_thread_blocked, id=4768, stack(0x00007f295fde4000,0x00007f295fee4aa8)]
  0x000055ddae980000 JavaThread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 97" [_thread_blocked, id=4689, stack(0x00007f295f3dc000,0x00007f295f4dcaa8)]
  0x000055ddae847800 JavaThread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 92" [_thread_blocked, id=4211, stack(0x00007f296131b000,0x00007f296141baa8)]
  0x000055dda5ac7800 JavaThread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 90" [_thread_blocked, id=4144, stack(0x00007f295f8e1000,0x00007f295f9e1aa8)]
  0x000055dda7a06800 JavaThread "Craft Scheduler Thread - 67" [_thread_blocked, id=3155, stack(0x00007f295f7e0000,0x00007f295f8e0aa8)]
  0x000055ddb164d000 JavaThread "pool-25-thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=2727, stack(0x00007f2961a20000,0x00007f2961b20aa8)]
  0x000055dda4ff5800 JavaThread "RxComputationThreadPool-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=499, stack(0x00007f295f0d7000,0x00007f295f1d7aa8)]
  0x000055dda850e000 JavaThread "RxComputationThreadPool-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=443, stack(0x00007f295f9e2000,0x00007f295fae2aa8)]
  0x000055ddaba5f800 JavaThread "RxComputationThreadPool-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=413, stack(0x00007f295fee5000,0x00007f295ffe5aa8)]
  0x000055ddac9bb800 JavaThread "RxComputationThreadPool-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=366, stack(0x00007f296191f000,0x00007f2961a1faa8)]
  0x000055ddabd4b000 JavaThread "RxComputationThreadPool-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=338, stack(0x00007f295d56e000,0x00007f295d66eaa8)]
  0x000055dda7376000 JavaThread "RxComputationThreadPool-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=337, stack(0x00007f296171d000,0x00007f296181daa8)]
  0x000055dda7f68000 JavaThread "RxComputationThreadPool-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=318, stack(0x00007f29640ef000,0x00007f29641efaa8)]
  0x000055dda5e83800 JavaThread "RxComputationThreadPool-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=305, stack(0x00007f295de6d000,0x00007f295df6daa8)]
  0x000055ddac7ae000 JavaThread "RxCachedWorkerPoolEvictor-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=304, stack(0x00007f295e06f000,0x00007f295e16faa8)]
  0x000055dda66f9000 JavaThread "pool-35-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=251, stack(0x00007f295d46d000,0x00007f295d56daa8)]
  0x000055dda7e5a800 JavaThread "CombatTagPlus ForceField Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=247, stack(0x00007f295d66f000,0x00007f295d76faa8)]
  0x000055dda97b4000 JavaThread "ProtocolLib-StructureCompiler 0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=245, stack(0x00007f295d869000,0x00007f295d969aa8)]
  0x000055dda9f08800 JavaThread "File IO Thread" [_thread_in_native, id=237, stack(0x00007f29606ae000,0x00007f29607aeaa8)]
  0x000055dda5324000 JavaThread "Chunk I/O Executor Thread-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=234, stack(0x00007f295dc6b000,0x00007f295dd6baa8)]
  0x000055ddaa8ce800 JavaThread "Chunk I/O Executor Thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=233, stack(0x00007f295dd6c000,0x00007f295de6caa8)]
  0x000055dda7798800 JavaThread "pool-39-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=231, stack(0x00007f295df6e000,0x00007f295e06eaa8)]
  0x000055dda6f90000 JavaThread "Query Listener #1" [_thread_in_native, id=192, stack(0x00007f295ffe6000,0x00007f29600e6aa8)]
  0x000055dda82e9000 JavaThread "factions-top-persistence-task" [_thread_blocked, id=189, stack(0x00007f29600e7000,0x00007f29601e7aa8)]
  0x000055dda3a09000 JavaThread "factions-top-chunk-task" [_thread_blocked, id=188, stack(0x00007f29601e8000,0x00007f29602e8aa8)]
  0x000055dda64ce800 JavaThread "MVStore background writer nio:/home/container/plugins/FactionsTop/database.mv.db" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=187, stack(0x00007f29605ad000,0x00007f29606adaa8)]
  0x000055dda7b55800 JavaThread "factions-top-sql-pool-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=184, stack(0x00007f29607af000,0x00007f29608afaa8)]
  0x000055ddaa1c7000 JavaThread "pool-7-thread-2" [_thread_blocked, id=170, stack(0x00007f2960cb0000,0x00007f2960db0aa8)]
  0x000055ddaa8fe800 JavaThread "litebans-pool housekeeper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=169, stack(0x00007f296121a000,0x00007f296131aaa8)]
  0x000055dda4184800 JavaThread "pool-36-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=164, stack(0x00007f296141c000,0x00007f296151caa8)]
  0x000055dda6f3c000 JavaThread "pool-31-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=158, stack(0x00007f296181e000,0x00007f296191eaa8)]
  0x000055dda3355800 JavaThread "pool-22-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=155, stack(0x00007f2963e6e000,0x00007f2963f6eaa8)]
  0x000055dda73f8800 JavaThread "Timer-2" [_thread_blocked, id=154, stack(0x00007f2961b21000,0x00007f2961c21aa8)]
  0x000055dda771b000 JavaThread "Thread-15" [_thread_in_native, id=140, stack(0x00007f2962822000,0x00007f2962922aa8)]
  0x000055dda3732800 JavaThread "Okio Watchdog" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=137, stack(0x00007f2962b23000,0x00007f2962c23aa8)]
  0x000055dda3737800 JavaThread "OkHttp ConnectionPool" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=136, stack(0x00007f2962c24000,0x00007f2962d24aa8)]
  0x000055dda76ee000 JavaThread "Timer-1" [_thread_blocked, id=132, stack(0x00007f2963125000,0x00007f2963225aa8)]
  0x000055dda3b16800 JavaThread "Thread-11" [_thread_blocked, id=130, stack(0x00007f2963426000,0x00007f2963526aa8)]
  0x000055dda6c39800 JavaThread "Thread-10" [_thread_blocked, id=129, stack(0x00007f2963527000,0x00007f2963627aa8)]
  0x000055dda57f7000 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=126, stack(0x00007f2963f6f000,0x00007f296406faa8)]
  0x000055dda3177800 JavaThread "pool-12-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=125, stack(0x00007f29638b0000,0x00007f29639b0aa8)]
  0x000055dda43de800 JavaThread "pool-4-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=113, stack(0x00007f296628a000,0x00007f296638aaa8)]
  0x000055dda398f000 JavaThread "Netty Epoll Server IO #3" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=92, stack(0x00007f2966649000,0x00007f2966749aa8)]
  0x000055dda5c31000 JavaThread "Netty Epoll Server IO #2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=91, stack(0x00007f2966df3000,0x00007f2966ef3aa8)]
  0x000055dda4c55000 JavaThread "Netty Epoll Server IO #1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=90, stack(0x00007f2967192000,0x00007f2967292aa8)]
  0x000055dda5d1e000 JavaThread "Netty Epoll Server IO #0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=89, stack(0x00007f2967293000,0x00007f2967393aa8)]
  0x000055dda4191800 JavaThread "PaperSpigot Watchdog Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=87, stack(0x00007f296759b000,0x00007f296769baa8)]
  0x000055dda4c82800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=85, stack(0x00007f296789c000,0x00007f296799caa8)]
  0x000055dda56ff000 JavaThread "Server console handler" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=83, stack(0x00007f296807a000,0x00007f296817aaa8)]
  0x000055dda32da800 JavaThread "Thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=82, stack(0x00007f296817b000,0x00007f296827baa8)]
  0x000055dda56fd800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=33, stack(0x00007f29aca84000,0x00007f29acb84aa8)]
  0x000055dda4049800 JavaThread "Server thread" [_thread_in_Java, id=81, stack(0x00007f296827c000,0x00007f296837caa8)]
  0x000055dda4048000 JavaThread "Server Infinisleeper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=80, stack(0x00007f2968675000,0x00007f2968775aa8)]
  0x000055dda4a32800 JavaThread "NonBlockingInputStreamThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=79, stack(0x00007f2968bc1000,0x00007f2968cc1aa8)]
  0x000055dda3f54000 JavaThread "Snooper Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=67, stack(0x00007f2968cc2000,0x00007f2968dc2aa8)]
  0x000055dda325a800 JavaThread "process reaper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=66, stack(0x00007f296ca7c000,0x00007f296cab5aa8)]
  0x000055dda2e8a000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=63, stack(0x00007f296cce2000,0x00007f296cde2aa8)]
  0x000055dda2df9000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=62, stack(0x00007f296cde4000,0x00007f296cee4aa8)]
  0x000055dda2df7000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=61, stack(0x00007f296cee6000,0x00007f296cfe6aa8)]
  0x000055dda2df4800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=60, stack(0x00007f296cfe8000,0x00007f296d0e8aa8)]
  0x000055dda2de4800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=59, stack(0x00007f296d0ea000,0x00007f296d1eaaa8)]
  0x000055dda2de2800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=58, stack(0x00007f296d1eb000,0x00007f296d2ebaa8)]
  0x000055dda2de0800 JavaThread "Surrogate Locker Thread (Concurrent GC)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=57, stack(0x00007f296d2ec000,0x00007f296d3ecaa8)]
  0x000055dda2db1000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=56, stack(0x00007f296d3ed000,0x00007f296d4edaa8)]
  0x000055dda2dae000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=55, stack(0x00007f296d4ee000,0x00007f296d5eeaa8)]
```

Comment: Please don't link your errors, copy them in here and format them properly. Links expire, and people who want to help you might not be able to see pastebin from work anyway.

Comment: Done thanks for the tip!

Comment: I've run a Minecraft server with OVH. If you are using shared hosting, it will cut off your resources suddenly, leaving the server with no RAM. It will then, of course, crash immediately with little to no explanation. This is because on shared hosting your resources are not guaranteed, they are only around if they're actually available to you. Are you using a VPS or a shared host?

Comment: I cri, the server I use is the MC-32 Dedi Server with 32gb ram yet I only use 16gb ram for the current server. It also has a i7-6700k, I pay all of this money for something that I thought would have been better but it turns out it crashes repeatedly for no reason